# Get previous item in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, iterator

How do I get the previous (and next) item in a 2 dimensional array easily?
I know you can iterate using:

```
 for (byte x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++) 
 {
   for (byte y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++) 
   {
        //Here I should get previous item if certain bool returns false
   }
 }
```

I could do `y--`. But what if `y` is the first element in the `x` row? Then `y = (getLength(1) -1)` and `x--`. Which looks kinda complex to me :s

Since my array has elements of custom type 'Field', I tried to make a previousField property using this code:

```
    Field previousField = null;
    foreach (Field field in this.Grid)
    {
        field.PreviousField = previousField;

        previousField = field;
    }
```

However, this does not work with the 'for' loop iteration. Since I'm iterating on 2 totally different ways now ><. I do not know how to create a nexField property.

So, How do I create a nextField property? If not possible, how can I iterate back and forward through my array? I do need an array since I need to use indexing in other parts of the code.

**EDIT:** Example;

I'm making a sudoku, using the backtrack algorithm. The 2D array represents the grid (9x9 for example). So I iterate through the array, inserting random digits (making use of optimistic, 'this should be fine', otherwise, we will go  back and change).

When inserting a digit, I validate if the digit is correct (unique in block, row and column). I try all possible digits (1-9). If there are no correct digits, then I probably made a fault in the previous cell (so I backtrack). If there are no valid digits there, then go to the previous field again. If a valid digit is found, then I go to the next digit again.

Comment: I would not use iterators , but regualar loops. And I would implement GetNext() GetPrev() functions for both x and y.

Comment: Could you post what the array variable looks like?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "previous item". Do you mean the previous item in the row, or in the entire array?

Comment: Ty for concern. I tryed to make my problem clearer by making an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you only really need your previous field for this iteration, you can just track it in your loop. Something like this:

```
Field previous = null;
for (byte x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++) 
{
    for (byte y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++) 
    {
         //Here I should get previous item if certain bool returns false
         // ....
         previous = grid[x,y];
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if the OP wants when the current value is at the beginning of a new row, the previous value will be the last value in the previous row.

Comment: But then how do I get the previous previous one? I should be able to move through the elements. So Since I moved from the original element to the previous one. Next element should give me the original one. And previous elements should, from perspective of the original element, be the same as 'previous previous element'

Comment: @user1933169, What you describe above is inconssitent. either you want a previous operation which gives you current index-1 , or you want to track items history - this is not the same.

Comment: dude, `var previous = null;` seriously! :p

Comment: Lol, the first element does not have a previous field. Thereby, I set it to null since you have to initialize an object in c# before using it.

Comment: well `var` is implicit typed variable, you can't assign `null` to it. So in this example context `object bla = null` would probably be better. :) I know it's just an example but just looks silly :)

Comment: Lol, look at code, I do object bla = null :p aka Field = custom object.. Ty for comment anyway

Comment: We are trying to help you. Please be polite and courteous, or we will not give our help.

Comment: He just means that the code as presented won't compile. `var previous = null;` can't compile. Also, I think people are replying to things that weren't directed at them... :)

Comment: @bas: Sorry about that, I was writing in a hurry and couldn't be bothered to look at what the OP was calling their objects. That and I've been doing a lot of Javascript lately!

Comment: @MattBurland haha no worries just had to say it. +1 for being cool :)